# Which exact chipset do I have?

Tags: cpu, chipset

Have a Lenovo Thinkpad E570, model 20H5CTO1WW, and trying to determine
exactly what components it has.  lspci tells me:

- CPU: Core i7-7500U
- Host bridge: Xeon E3-1200 v6
- There are also several references to the "Sunrise Point" chipset.

Having trouble reconciling this information.

This CPU is 7th-generation Kaby Lake architecture, and Wikipedia tells
me this uses the LGA 1151 socket.  The Wikipedia page for that socket
suggests that revision 1 of that socket is found on 100 series Skylake
chipsets (codenamed "Sunrise Point") but are compatible with Kaby Lake
architecture with a BIOS update.  So initially I though my chipset was
probably one of the following:

- H110
- B150
- Q150
- H170
- Q170
- Z170

I couldn't figure out how to then determine which of these is the most
likely candidate.

However, the Xeon northbridge also has me confused.  For revision 2 of
this socket there are a couple of Xeon chipsets also codenamed Sunrise
Point, of which only the C236 is a probably candidate (since I have an
integrated GPU and the others either don't support that or are too
recent).  But then I read that revision 2 of the socket is
incompatible with 100 and 200 series CPUs, that is, it is only
compatible with Coffee Lake architecture, which would seem to rule out
my Kaby Lake CPUs.

So... which of these should I investigate further, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than guessing, the easiest way to find out what chipset you have is to run a tool such as [CPU-z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

It will tell you exactly what chipset is on your motherboard:

[image]
(Image borrowed from [Guru3D](https://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/msi-x99a-godlike-motherboard-review,10.html))

Otherwise in Linux the command `dmidecode -t 2` will apparently give you some information on your motherboard, amongst which should be the chipset model:

[image]

(Image from [WinAero:Finding the motherboard model in Linux](https://winaero.com/blog/find-motherboard-model-linux/))